# Ошибка в консоли диспетчера пакетов(Package Manager Console) Invoke-RestMethod. Ошибка при тестировании контроллера

Tags: c#

```
PM> invoke - RestMethod http://localhost:44346/api/users -Method GET
invoke : Имя "invoke" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность на
писания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1
+ invoke - RestMethod http://localhost:44346/api/users -Method GET
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (invoke:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Нужно загрузить какой то отдельный пакет для Invoke-RestMethod?

https://github.com/nekiymolla/medapi-trial-.git

Comment: `invoke - RestMethod` откуда здесь пробелы взялись? `Invoke-RestMethod` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: привычка семантики, даже с пробелами та же ошибка

Comment: Так уберите их и напишите команду так, как по ссылке в документации указано.

Comment: Даже без пробелов*

Comment: `Install-Package Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility` https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/